# Exceptions don#t work good in cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write for a cursor who dispay a list of employees selected mit paramaters from_employee and to_employee  two exceptions. First need to work when there is no rows were  selected and another one when just one row was selected. My code just blocks all the time sqldeveloper and it starts to nerve. I need a help!!!

```
 `set serveroutput on;
set echo on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE output_employee_set (
 from_employee IN NUMBER,
 to_employee IN NUMBER,
 ascending_order IN BOOLEAN)
 IS
    v_id            EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
    v_ename         EMP.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
    v_surname       EMP.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
    v_email         EMP.EMAIL%TYPE;
    v_telefon       EMP.PHONE_NUMBER%TYPE;
    v_hiredate      EMP.HIRE_DATE%TYPE;
    v_sal           EMP.SALARY%TYPE;
    v_job           JOBS.JOB_TITLE%TYPE;
    v_dname         DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
    v_manager       EMP.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
    one_element     Exception;
    no_element      Exception;
    counter         NUMBER;

    CURSOR emp_cur IS
       SELECT  e.EMPLOYEE_ID,e.FIRST_NAME,e.LAST_NAME,e.EMAIL,e.PHONE_NUMBER,e.HIRE_DATE,e.SALARY,j.JOB_TITLE,d.DEPARTMENT_NAME,m.LAST_NAME

        FROM emp e LEFT OUTER JOIN employees m ON (m.employee_id = e.manager_id), DEPARTMENTS d, JOBS j
        WHERE 
           e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
          AND e.JOB_ID=j.JOB_ID
          ORDER BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID ;


BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(e.employee_id) INTO counter FROM emp e LEFT OUTER JOIN employees m ON (m.employee_id = e.manager_id), DEPARTMENTS d, JOBS j
        WHERE 
           e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
          AND e.JOB_ID=j.JOB_ID
          ORDER BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID ;

 IF   ascending_order  THEN
    OPEN emp_cur;

    LOOP
    IF v_id BETWEEN from_employee AND to_employee THEN
        FETCH emp_cur INTO v_id,v_ename,v_surname,v_email,v_telefon,v_hiredate,v_sal,v_job,v_dname,v_manager;

        IF emp_cur%NOTFOUND THEN RAISE no_element;
        EXIT;
            ELSE
            FETCH emp_cur INTO v_id,v_ename,v_surname,v_email,v_telefon,v_hiredate,v_sal,v_job,v_dname,v_manager;
             IF counter=1 THEN RAISE one_element;
             ELSE

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number         : ' || v_id);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name           : ' || v_ename||' '||v_surname);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Email          : ' || v_email);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Telefon NR.    : ' || v_telefon);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Eingestellt am : ' || v_hiredate);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Gehalt         : ' || v_sal);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Beruf ID       : ' || v_job);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department     : ' || v_dname);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Vorgesetzter   : ' || v_manager);
     END IF;
     END IF;
    END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE emp_cur;



 END IF;
   EXCEPTION 
   WHEN one_element THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Just one employee was selected');
    WHEN no_element THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No employees were selected'); 
END;
/
 `
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few small errors in your code.

First error: `(m.employee_id = e.manager_id)` - it should be: `(e.employee_id = m.manager_id)`.

Second error: When you define the cursor, you must use an alias for `manager last_name`, because you first select the `employer's last name` and there will be two rows called `LAST_NAME`.

Third error: You don't have any initialized `v_id` in that LOOP. 
So, you must enter the loop, fetch the `employee_ID` in `v_id` and then you check if `v_id` is between `from_employee` and `to_employee`.

I rewrote your code using a FOR LOOP to fetch from cursor and it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE output_employee_set (
from_employee IN NUMBER,
to_employee IN NUMBER,
ascending_order IN BOOLEAN)
IS
   v_id            EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
   v_ename         EMP.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
   v_surname       EMP.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
   v_email         EMP.EMAIL%TYPE;
   v_telefon       EMP.PHONE_NUMBER%TYPE;
   v_hiredate      EMP.HIRE_DATE%TYPE;
   v_sal           EMP.SALARY%TYPE;
   v_job           JOBS.JOB_TITLE%TYPE;
   v_dname         DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
   v_manager       EMP.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
   one_element     Exception;
   no_element      Exception;
   counter         NUMBER;

   CURSOR emp_cur IS
     SELECT  e.EMPLOYEE_ID, e.FIRST_NAME,
           e.LAST_NAME, e.EMAIL,
           e.PHONE_NUMBER, e.HIRE_DATE, 
           e.SALARY,  j.JOB_TITLE,  d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, m.LAST_NAME as manager_name

    FROM emp e LEFT OUTER JOIN employees m ON (e.employee_id = m.manager_id), DEPARTMENTS d, JOBS j
    WHERE 
       e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
      AND e.JOB_ID=j.JOB_ID
      ORDER BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID ;    
BEGIN

   SELECT COUNT(e.employee_id) INTO counter FROM emp e LEFT OUTER JOIN employees m ON (e.employee_id = m.manager_id), DEPARTMENTS d, JOBS j
      WHERE 
         e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
        AND e.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID
        ORDER BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID ;

 --Updated
 IF (counter = 0 ) THEN
    RAISE no_element;
 END IF;  

 IF   ascending_order = true  THEN    
   FOR index_cursor IN emp_cur LOOP        

    v_id := index_cursor.employee_id; 
    IF (v_id >= from_employee AND v_id <= to_employee) THEN

          v_ename := index_cursor.first_name;
          v_surname := index_cursor.last_name;
          v_email := index_cursor.email;
          v_telefon := index_cursor.phone_number;
          v_hiredate := index_cursor.hire_date;
          v_sal := index_cursor.salary;
          v_job := index_cursor.job_title;
          v_dname := index_cursor.department_name;
          v_manager := index_cursor.manager_name;

          -- Or you can directly print the content using 
          -- DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number :' || index_cursor.employee_id);

          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number         : ' || v_id);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name           : ' || v_ename||' '||v_surname);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Email          : ' || v_email);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Telefon NR.    : ' || v_telefon);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Eingestellt am : ' || v_hiredate);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Gehalt         : ' || v_sal);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Beruf ID       : ' || v_job);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department     : ' || v_dname);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Vorgesetzter   : ' || v_manager);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');

          --Update
          IF (counter = 1 ) THEN
            EXIT;
          END IF;   

    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  IF (counter = 1) THEN
    RAISE one_element;
  END IF;
END IF;
 EXCEPTION 
  WHEN one_element THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Just one employee was selected');
  WHEN no_element THEN 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No employees were selected'); 
END;
/
```

Comment: thank you so much, but it still doesn't show an exception when you for example select just one row or no rows, when they for example don't exist. Why doesn't show it one row was selected or no rows were selected?

Comment: Oh, 
Sorry about that part. 

You have the counter that tells you how many rows you will have.
You can write before enter the loop the following code:


`IF (counter=0) THEN   
          RAISE no_element;  
 END IF;  

 IF (counter=1) THEN  
          RAISE one_element;  
 END IF;` .

Comment: do you mean so:  FOR index_cursor IN emp_cur
   
   LOOP        

    v_id := index_cursor.employee_id; 
    IF (v_id > from_employee AND v_id < to_employee) THEN
     IF (counter=0) THEN RAISE no_element; 
     END IF; 
     IF (counter=1) THEN RAISE one_element; 
     END IF;

Comment: Aa.. No. :)

In this case the `RAISE no_element;` will  be an unreachable line. 

I will update the code in my answer and comment the lines that you won't need.

Comment: oh thank you so much. You will really help me so much. Because i am just blocked on this point and can't even find a good info in Web about Exceptions in cursor:'(

Comment: I've updated the lines up there. 
Now it works fine. 

If this is the solution for what you need, mark this question as Answered.

Comment: unfortunately it still doesn't work well. Now when i call one row, For example i write Execute ....(203,203,true) it shows me an employee with id 203 and not the msg that 'Just one employee was selected' :(. Maybe i haven't explained right what i need.

Comment: I don't know yet, but there is a problem with raising an exception inside a loop. 

In your case, you can write that `IF ( counter = 1)` after the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');`. 
But, the code should look like this: 
`... 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' ');   IF( counter = 1) THEN EXIT; END IF;`. 

First we exit the loop and just after that we `RAISE one_element;`. 

*(I don't know yet, but I'll search for this loop raise.)

Comment: Thanks. You've really helped me much. And if you find where is the problem will be great!!!,

Comment: In your case, you needed to raise `one_element` exception after you print out the information about the employer.  (When I first executed the code, it didn't work, and so I wrote that EXIT. But now I saw it works fine if, instead EXIT, I write `RAISE one_element`.
.
 I've found here (http://www.coderanch.com/t/80294/Oracle-OAS/EXCEPTION-LOOP) that you can write an exception right next to your `RAISE statement`, but you must be careful not to forget the  `BEGIN` and `END;` words for that block.

Comment: your updated code works with one_element now. it gives out employee and also a msg that just one employee was selected, and where should i put no_employee, when no employees were selected?

Comment: however not so properly. it shows now all the time a msg that one employee was selected.

Comment: * It is because we have that Raise after the loop, so when we enter the loop, it will always raise the one_element. (My bad). 
Instead EXIT, write there `RAISE one_element;` and delete `RAISE one_element` after the loop. And it should be done now.

Comment: i know it irritates. But now it ignores this exception at all:(

Comment: I've compiled again the code I wrote there (see if are updates), and it works fine. 
How do you call the procedure?

Comment: No for me it shows the employee and no msg that just one employee was selected. to call procedure i write Execute output_employee_set(203,203,true);

Comment: Check again the lines and see if there are all correct. 
You may copy/paste the code, it should work. 
But, SQL Developer might have some errors, it happened many times on me.  
Try to disconnect and connect again, then execute the procedure and the query (don't forget to `set serveroutput on;`).

Comment: I have made all points what you've said. But everything is still the same. When you compile and run it, do you get a msg that just one employyee was selected?

Comment: Yes, I have the result for that employee and the message: one employee was selected.

Comment: No for me everything is still the same(((

Comment: If you can't raise that exception in FOR LOOP, then you can put again there `EXIT` statement, and outside the loop, you can check again `IF (counter = 1) then RAISE one_element; end if;` . 
In this case, if there are more elements, you also check if counter is one, and that exception will not show up every time you execute the procedure.

Comment: so i need to write EXIT WHEN counter=1; after ... FOR index_cursor IN emp_cur LOOP..... And also IF (counter = 1) then RAISE one_element; end if; after END LOOP;    I've made it, it still doesn't show me a msg

Answer (score 0):

Why not insert condition on EMPLOYEE_ID just in the queries calculating 'counter' and forming 'emp_cur' respectively?
For me works this (code based on a variant by @PianoSong):

```
PROCEDURE output_employee_set (
    from_employee IN NUMBER,
    to_employee IN NUMBER,
    ascending_order IN BOOLEAN)
    IS
       v_id            EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
       v_ename         EMP.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
       v_surname       EMP.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
       v_email         EMP.EMAIL%TYPE;
       v_telefon       EMP.PHONE_NUMBER%TYPE;
       v_hiredate      EMP.HIRE_DATE%TYPE;
       v_sal           EMP.SALARY%TYPE;
       v_job           JOBS.JOB_TITLE%TYPE;
       v_dname         DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
       v_manager       EMP.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
       one_element     Exception;
       no_element      Exception;
       counter         NUMBER;

       CURSOR emp_cur IS
         SELECT  e.EMPLOYEE_ID, e.FIRST_NAME,
               e.LAST_NAME, e.EMAIL,
               e.PHONE_NUMBER, e.HIRE_DATE, 
               e.SALARY,  j.JOB_TITLE,  d.DEPARTMENT_NAME, m.LAST_NAME as manager_name

        FROM emp e LEFT OUTER JOIN employees m ON (e.employee_id = m.manager_id), DEPARTMENTS d, JOBS j
        WHERE 
           e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
          AND e.JOB_ID=j.JOB_ID
          AND e.EMPLOYEE_ID>=from_employee
          AND e.EMPLOYEE_ID<=to_employee
          ORDER BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID ;    
    BEGIN

       SELECT COUNT(e.employee_id) INTO counter FROM emp e LEFT OUTER JOIN employees m ON (e.employee_id = m.manager_id), DEPARTMENTS d, JOBS j
          WHERE 
             e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
            AND e.JOB_ID = j.JOB_ID
            AND e.EMPLOYEE_ID>=from_employee
            AND e.EMPLOYEE_ID<=to_employee
            ORDER BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID ;

     IF   ascending_order = true  THEN   
       IF (counter = 0 ) THEN
          RAISE no_element;
       ELSIF (counter = 1 ) THEN
          RAISE one_element;
       END IF;  

       FOR index_cursor IN emp_cur LOOP        
              v_ename := index_cursor.first_name;
              v_surname := index_cursor.last_name;
              v_email := index_cursor.email;
              v_telefon := index_cursor.phone_number;
              v_hiredate := index_cursor.hire_date;
              v_sal := index_cursor.salary;
              v_job := index_cursor.job_title;
              v_dname := index_cursor.department_name;
              v_manager := index_cursor.manager_name;

              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number         : ' || v_id);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name           : ' || v_ename||' '||v_surname);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Email          : ' || v_email);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Telefon NR.    : ' || v_telefon);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Eingestellt am : ' || v_hiredate);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Gehalt         : ' || v_sal);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Beruf ID       : ' || v_job);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department     : ' || v_dname);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Vorgesetzter   : ' || v_manager);
              DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
     EXCEPTION 
      WHEN one_element THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Just one employee was selected');
      WHEN no_element THEN 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No employees were selected'); 
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      set serveroutput on;
      set echo on;
      CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE output_employee_set (
       from_employee IN NUMBER,
       to_employee IN NUMBER,
       ascending_order IN BOOLEAN)
       IS

          v_id            EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE;
          v_ename         EMP.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
          v_surname       EMP.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
          v_email         EMP.EMAIL%TYPE;
          v_telefon       EMP.PHONE_NUMBER%TYPE;
          v_hiredate      EMP.HIRE_DATE%TYPE;
          v_sal           EMP.SALARY%TYPE;
          v_job           JOBS.JOB_TITLE%TYPE;
          v_dname         DEPARTMENTS.DEPARTMENT_NAME%TYPE;
          v_manager       EMP.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
          one_element     Exception;
         no_element      Exception;
         counter         NUMBER;

          CURSOR emp_cur IS
             SELECT  e.EMPLOYEE_ID,e.FIRST_NAME,e.LAST_NAME,e.EMAIL,e.PHONE_NUMBER,e.HIRE_DATE,e.SALARY,j.JOB_TITLE,d.DEPARTMENT_NAME,m.LAST_NAME

              FROM emp e, emp m, DEPARTMENTS d, JOBS j
              WHERE 
                 e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
                AND e.MANAGER_ID=m.EMPLOYEE_ID
                AND e.JOB_ID=j.JOB_ID
                ORDER BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID ;

            CURSOR emp_cur_desc IS
             SELECT  e.EMPLOYEE_ID,e.FIRST_NAME,e.LAST_NAME,e.EMAIL,e.PHONE_NUMBER,e.HIRE_DATE,e.SALARY,j.JOB_TITLE,d.DEPARTMENT_NAME,m.LAST_NAME

              FROM emp e, emp m, DEPARTMENTS d, JOBS j
              WHERE 
                 e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID
                AND e.MANAGER_ID=m.EMPLOYEE_ID
                AND e.JOB_ID=j.JOB_ID
                ORDER BY e.EMPLOYEE_ID DESC;
      BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(1000000);
      --counter
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO counter
      FROM emp 
      WHERE employee_id
      BETWEEN from_employee AND to_employee;

      --Exceptions
       IF (counter = 0 ) THEN
          RAISE no_element;
       END IF; 

      IF (counter = 1) THEN
          RAISE one_element;
        END IF;

        IF   ascending_order  THEN
          OPEN emp_cur;

          LOOP
              FETCH emp_cur INTO v_id,v_ename,v_surname,v_email,v_telefon,v_hiredate,v_sal,v_job,v_dname,v_manager;
              EXIT WHEN emp_cur%NOTFOUND;
              IF v_id BETWEEN from_employee AND to_employee THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number         : ' || v_id);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name           : ' || v_ename||' '||v_surname);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Email          : ' || v_email);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Telefon NR.    : ' || v_telefon);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Eingestellt am : ' || v_hiredate);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Gehalt         : ' || v_sal);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Beruf ID       : ' || v_job);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department     : ' || v_dname);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Vorgesetzter   : ' || v_manager);
           END IF;
          END LOOP;

          CLOSE emp_cur;
         END IF;
         IF  NOT ascending_order  THEN
          OPEN emp_cur_desc;

          LOOP
              FETCH emp_cur_desc INTO v_id,v_ename,v_surname,v_email,v_telefon,v_hiredate,v_sal,v_job,v_dname,v_manager;
              EXIT WHEN emp_cur_desc%NOTFOUND;
              IF v_id BETWEEN from_employee AND to_employee THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Number         : ' || v_id);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Name           : ' || v_ename||' '||v_surname);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Email          : ' || v_email);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Telefon NR.    : ' || v_telefon);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Eingestellt am : ' || v_hiredate);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Gehalt         : ' || v_sal);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Beruf ID       : ' || v_job);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Department     : ' || v_dname);
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Vorgesetzter   : ' || v_manager);
           END IF;
          END LOOP;

          CLOSE emp_cur_desc;
         END IF;

         EXCEPTION 
        WHEN one_element THEN 
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Just one employee was selected');
        WHEN no_element THEN 
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No employees were selected');

      END;
      /
      EXECUTE output_employee_set(208,209,FALSE);
```